# nodejs XHR alternative for http request

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I need to use an API for an application I am builiding but the API doesn't allow for CORS, how else can I make GET and POST requests to the website without using XHR. I've been looking at websockets and socket.io but it doesn't seem like I can make http requests with them.

My other solution is creating using PHP or curl to make the requests but I feel like that isn't a good a idea.

Edit: More info

The API I want to use is https://bitcoinindex.es/api

I want to grab the exchange prices that are listed and list them from greatest to least.

I was using AngularJS to make the first API request here is my code

```
  $http.get("https://bitcoinindex.es/api/v0.1/coinbase/usd/btc/last").success (JSON)
```

Comment: do you have some more information? which api you want to use? what do you want to build?

Comment: Added more information

Comment: Why is this tagged `node.js`? From a node server, you can make every kind of request that you want and don't need to care about CORS.

Comment: Sorry I am new to node, Also I was using AngularJS to make the http request, how do I make it with node?

Comment: The bottom line is you should make an http request to your node server running on the same host as your angular app. Then server side use the request module to make the request to the Bitcoin API and return to your angular request.

Comment: Ok I am understanding now, I thought angularJS and nodeJS were this one sort of entity that worked together. So When I did http.get I thought it was a request being sent from node.

Comment: @grasshopper: No. One is executing on the server (with respective privileges), the other is executed by the client (with his authentications and respective restrictions).

Answer (score 2):

As a PHP developer moving from a traditional LAMP stack to angularJS and nodejs there were a few assumptions I made that were wrong.

**All Http request are the same**

Now of course I knew that there was GET, POST, and PUT but I thought a get request was the same across the board, this is not true. There are traditional request made from the backend of an application from a server using libraries such as curl. These http request are made before a webpage loads.

With AngularJS request are made from the front-end, meaning after the webpage is loaded the request is made. This is called **XHR** and is supported by all modern browsers, the thing with XHR is that it can leave user data vulnerable so it only works if the request is made to a location on the same server. If you're making a request to a different server then **CORS** needs to be enabled by the server response is coming from and can be configured through the access-control-allow-origin header.

**NodeJS is some type of front-end hippy code**

Again coming from PHP I didn't understand that nodeJS is an **actual server** just like an apache server, and can make the traditional request mentioned in the first section.

**Making request**

Making nodeJS request is very simple with the nodejs [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) library.

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
  }
})
```

Comment: request is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some  request from server side using nodejs some module like [Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) could help you.

Comment: It's deprecated.